# elementary OS 14.04 to 15.10 upgrade issues

Tags: release-freya, updates

Updating from Freya to wily is quite annoying at this point. I'm somewhat a newbie to Linux, but when I run update commands in terminal or software update I get the following:

```
W:Failed to fetch_http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, 

W:Failed to fetch_http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
,

 W:Failed to fetch_http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
,

 W:Failed to fetch_http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
,

 W:Failed to fetch_http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, 

W:Failed to fetch_http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
,

 E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Maybe add the command you used to update or upgrade and get to this point.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to upgrade elementary OS Freya to Ubuntu 15.10. You will break your system since elementary hasn't released packages for Ubuntu 15.10.

If you want to upgrade Freya then **wait** for elementary OS Loki (based on Ubuntu 16.04) to be released.

Answer (score 0):

Although elementary OS is **based on Ubuntu**, **you must wait** for elementary OS 0.4 (Loki) release. It's possible to add Ubuntu repositories, but you can destroy your Elementary.

Comment: Don't add duplicate answers.